# I want to extract a value from a response and use it in the next request

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to extract name from here

```
{"name":"morpheus","job":"leader","id":"938","createdAt":"2022-08-16T18:37:45.745Z"}
```

i used `"name":"(.*?)"`, as a regex but when check the reponse i found it as `${name}` not as `morpheus`

Comment: It looks like you've received Json. Try to use Json parser of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions is not the best idea, JMeter comes with [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to fetch the required data from JSON responses.

Suggested JSON Path Extractor setup:

[image]

[image]

The Regular Expression Extractor should also work if you configure it like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the third screenshot worked with me I just needed to select body cuz it send the name in the body